# Merging two rigs with same bone structure?

Tags: rigging, bones

I have a problem and I'm not sure how to go about fixing it. I've imported a valve qc rig and I need to merge what appears to be a meshless bone rig with a meshed rig. I thought about doing it in unity, but I thought I'd ask here first. Unity doesn't allow merging of non-human rigs

[image]

Comment: it look like you need to clarify wat exactly you need, from your image I only can assume that you want to attach the weapon to your Arms? or do you want to copy the animation from the unskinned Rig to the Skinned? What i can see from the picture is, that it looks like the importer didn't exactly create a blender armature object from your file, only meshes parented in a hirachy.

Comment: The model with the meshless armature has the same bone structure as the arms with a mesh. Valves software allow different hand models to be swapped in real time, but I'm incapable of doing that in unity without a lot of work